# "getEditors" method returns partial users only

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with several users allowed to access.

For security managent, the system is supposed to email a list of accounts that access is granted; however, it contains a partial users and some is missing.
I want to find a solution to include every single user in the monthly email report.

Here's what I wrote:

```
const editorsSprTR =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(UNITED_MASTER_ID).getEditors();`
const totalTREditors = editorsSprTR.length`

var editorsTRStr = '（1） List of users：' + totalTREditors + 'persons\\n'
  for (let i in editorsSprTR){
    let email = editorsSprTR\[i\]
    var editorsTRStr = editorsTRStr + '　・' + email + '\\n';
  }
```

To add more info, a missing member uses the company's corporate domain.

I granted access to my personal account (not under company's domain) and executed the above code and it returned the complete set of users. So I'm wondering there's a problem in scope or something.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps you require getViewers as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.